# Encrypt config file values

Tags: encryption, web-config

I have a web.config file, in that file I just want to encrypt only "connectionStrings" value, for that I am able to do it in manually by using below command in command prompt as Admin mode.
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -pef "connectionStrings" "Website Folder(web.config) path"

Now, I want to do it in Automatic way by using command line task in Azure DevOps pipeline. If I use same command in pipeline, it got succeeded but values are not encrypted, might be we are not running with Admin mode.

Can anyone help me how to run the command in command line task with admin rights in ADO pipeline ?

Thanks in advance.